# In SpEL, create a new inline list using a previously-constructed list

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el

In spring-integration I'm wanting to "update" a list of values that are kept within a message header, using a header-enricher.

In my example, I've created an inline list `{'x', 'y'}` and I want to add `'z'` to that list.  I haven't found an example of how to do this in SpEL.  It seems like it should be a common, trivial thing to do.

```
<si:header-enricher>
    <si:header name="myList" expression="{ 'x', 'y' }" />
</si:header-enricher>

...

<si:header-enricher default-overwrite="true" >
    <!-- CLEARLY THIS DOESN'T WORK BUT USING TO DEMONSTRATE THE DESIRED RESULT -->
    <si:header name="myList" expression="{ headers.myList, 'z' }" />
</si:header-enricher>
```

How does one indicate that you want to create a new inline list that is the result of adding a value to an existing list?

In the demonstration code, the outcome would be `[ [ 'x', 'y' ], 'z' ]` rather than the desired `['x', 'y', 'z' ]`.

thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the Java DSL, but the expressions will work in XML too

```java
@Bean
IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(() -> "foo", e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
            .enrichHeaders(headers -> headers
                    .headerExpression("list", "{ 'x', 'y' }"))
            .enrichHeaders(headers -> headers
                    .headerExpression("list", "T(java.util.stream.Stream).concat(headers.list.stream(), "
                            + "{ 'z' }.stream()).collect(T(java.util.stream.Collectors).toList())")
                    .defaultOverwrite(true))
            .log()
            .get();
}
```

Result:

```
GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={list=[x, y, z], ...
```

**EDIT**

Here's another alternative:

```java
public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public MyList(List<T> original, T... elements) {
        super(original);
        for (T element : elements) {
            add(element);
        }
    }

}
```

Then `"new com.example.demo.MyList(headers.list, 'z')"`

Comment: That's fairly overkill for a simple expression that returns an existing list with a new item added to it.  I'm currently trying the SpEL custom function approach but it seems daft to have to add a new function for such an obvious primitive.  I agree that your proposal works from a result viewpoint, but it's not very readable.

Comment: I added another simpler solution.

Comment: The `headerExpression` (as many other in Spring Integration components) is about taking the value from context, so the expression by itself must return. The SpEL language is fully based on Java API with some minor syntax sugar. Since there is no clean API for `List` like `expand`, therefore it is expected that SpEL solution for your request is not going to be so simple. Of course you can implement something like an `#expand(headers.myList, 'z')`, but you still have to implement and register that SpEL-function: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/spel.html#spel

Comment: I'm quite used to using xpath3 as an expression language so I'm looking for something that is as expressive and as compact.  I guess that I'm expecting too much from SpEL.  Being able to have a concise, readable expression within SpEL should be a goal for any spring application.  I am trying to get SpEL custom functions to work and getting some limited success but running into some problems that I'll put into another SO item.  Thanks for the help and pointers.

Comment: In fact, no problem with SpEL functions, just a PEBKAC problem.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, and in case it's interesting for someone else, I'm posting a solution using custom SpEL functions, recommended by @Artem.

Adding a static method into an abstract class for list concatenation:

```java
package me.myself;

...

public abstract class MySpelFunctions {

    public static <T> List<T> listConcat(Iterable<? extends T> a, Iterable<? extends T> b) {
        return unmodifiableList(Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(a, b)));
    }

}
```

Then using the namespace support to add this custom function to the evaluation context:

```xml
<int:spel-function id="listConcat" 
                   class="me.myself.MySpelFunctions" 
                   method="listConcat(java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Iterable)" />
```

We can now use the custom function within the SpEL expression for the header-enricher:

```xml
<si:header-enricher>
    <si:header name="myList" expression="{ 'x', 'y' }" />
</si:header-enricher>

...

<si:header-enricher default-overwrite="true" >
    <si:header name="myList" expression="#listConcat( headers.myList, { 'z' } )" />
</si:header-enricher>
```

Thanks again for your help in arriving at a readable solution.